# script for deleting queues using a certain prefix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ibm-mq

i have a file named "Output_File.txt" containing a list of local queues and i want to write a script to delete those queues. what i wrote is:

```
queuelist=`wc -l Output_File.txt | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`
for (( currentline=1; currentline<=queuelist; currentline++ ))
do
   currentqueue=`awk -v x="$currentline" 'NR==x {print $1}' Output_File.txt
   echo "delete qlocal( $currentqueue )" | runmqsc
done
echo "the queues were deleted"
exit 0
```

the problem is that the script does delete the queues but prints for every deleted queue the following output:

```
1 : delete qlocal ( -queue_name- )
AMQ8007: WEBSPHERE MQ QUEUE DELETED.
NO COMMANDS HAVE SYNTAX ERROR.
ALL VALID MQSC COMMAND WERE PROCESSED.
```

how can i alter the code to delete the queues without printing the output above? thanks.

Comment: just use `echo "delete qlocal( $currentqueue )" | runmqsc > /dev/null` inside your for loop

Comment: @NR no problem :) posting it as an answer so that you can mark the question solved(click the tick beside the answer )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `echo "delete qlocal( $currentqueue )" | runmqsc > /dev/null` inside your for loop to direct all output of that command to blackhole `/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this quite a bit since awk will go through each line by default, no need to count the lines and then use a for loop inside awk.

```
awk awk '{print "delete qlocal("$1")"}' Output_File.txt | runmqsc > /dev/null

echo "the queues were deleted"
exit 0
```

**Note that this does not do any type of error checking to determine if the delete was successful, it could fail for a number of reasons such as a incorrect queue name, a queue has messages still on it, a queue which is currently opened by a process.**